# Remote desktop resolution

Tags: remote-desktop, remote

I'm connecting to a Windows desktop through Remote Desktop Viewer but their desktop is so small that it's to difficult to work with it. Is there way to increase the resolution?

Comment: You might want to try Remmina for RDP to Windows machines.  It's got a few more features and you can set the resolution you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try remmina remote desktop manager, I use it and it solved that and others problems.